# alarm set through AlarmManager isn't working

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, foreground-service

I am creating an application where I am trying to push a notification if google chrome is being used for too long. I am using accessibility service to detect which application is being used and I have written conditionals according to my vision of when the notification should be pushed. It works perfectly till here. Then I have tried to set an alarm using AlarmListener and this is where the problem lies. The PendingIntent(which triggers a foreground service which in turn fires the notification) passed as an argument to AlarmListener doesn't work. Please tell me where I am going wrong:

ApplicationListener.java

```
       public class ApplicationListenerService extends AccessibilityService {

    public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(String title, String content, String channel_id, int priority) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setPriority(priority);
        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {

        String packageName = accessibilityEvent.getPackageName().toString();

        if (!packageName.equals("com.android.systemui")) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(
                    "ApplicationListener", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            String storedPackage = sharedPref.getString("current_running_application", "none");

            if (storedPackage.equals("none")) {
                if (packageName.equals("com.android.chrome")) {
                    //instead of chrome check for all blacklisted apps
                    Log.d("obscure_tag", "chrome has been detected for the first time...starting alarm");
                    editor.putString("current_running_application", packageName);
                    editor.apply();
                    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1,  intent, 0);
                    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                            System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000,
                            alarmIntent);

                }
            } else if (storedPackage.equals(packageName)) {
                Log.d("obscure_tag", "chrome has been detected for the second time..doing nothing");
            } else {
                //delete alarm and stored package
                Log.d("obscure_tag", "different app is detected...alarm getting cancelled...");
                editor.clear();
                editor.apply();
                AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
                alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d("obscure_tag", "service is interrupted");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();

        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;

        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;

        info.notificationTimeout = 100;

        this.setServiceInfo(info);
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(Context context, String title, String content, String channel_id, int priority) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setPriority(priority);
        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(0, createNotification(context, "Demo task", "this task is incomplete", "task_reminders", 4).build());
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I have made used a broadcast receiver instead of a foreground service right now. Still this isn't working.

Comment: Does the `BroadcastReceiver` get called? Add logging in `onReceive()` to determine this. Also, have you added a `<receiver>` declaration for `AlarmReceiver` to your manifest?

Comment: Yes broadcast receiver does get called...Yes I did that...Apparently using AlarmManager.setAlarmClock solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of things but what finally solved my problem is using AlarmManager.setAlarmClock method...